# Paypal checkout opens on a separate tab - how to change this?

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I have found that the Paypal generated buttons is a very good solution for my wife's website. However, whenever someone presses on the "add to cart" button, he/she is taken to a separate Internet Explorer tab. That's fine. However, if they chose to "continue shopping", IE tries to close the Paypal tab and asks the user's permission to do so. This is not really ideal from the user experience point of view.

Can I force the Paypal Checkout to open in the same IE tab as the main website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Standard shopping cart will always function that way.  I highly recommend you go with your own shopping cart instead.  That way there are no new windows/tabs at all, and the redirection doesn't happen until the person is ready to pay.

There are lots of options for doing this.  You could build a cart into your site as a custom solution, or what would be even better would be to go with something like WordPress and WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid redirecting to a different tab, you can use minicart PayPal plugin.
You just need to include the following lines of code inside your

```
<script>
    paypal.minicart.render();
</script>
```

MiniJS [Demo](http://minicartjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, in your  check out button you should have target="_self" like this:

```html
<form id="paypal-checkout-button" target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess around guys!

Just remove **`target="paypal"`** attribute from the paypal form.

```
  <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
```

change to

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
```

This will now open paypal in the same tab/page of the browser.